# How to find database path in Android 4.4 (API level: 19)?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

Trying to read values from the database, that is created in webview using javascript, but unable to get the database path using

```
getDatabasePath()
```

Which seems to be deprecated is there is any solution or work around for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the documentation `getDatabasePath()` is not marked as deprecated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#getDatabasePath() - @Henry check at the link above

Comment: I looked up `android.content.Context.getDatabasePath()`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: sorted out the issue by myself. In kitkat 4.4 they seems to move the default database location from {app package name}/databases/{datbase_name} to {app package name}/app_webview/databases/file__0/{:id}, where id is the database name where the web sql data is saved by JS. The id is obtained by querying Datbases.db

Comment: can you explain what exactly you did @N20084753? I am trying the same but unable to resolve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String webviewDBPath = getFilesDir().getParent() + "/";  // getFilesDir().getParent() returns base path of app private data
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 18) { // Below kitkat
    webviewDBPath += <ur old db folder>;
}
webview.getSettings().setDatabasePath(webviewDBPath);
```

From kitkat, we can't change webview database path. Default database path is /data/data/{package name}/app_webview/databases/. For below kitkat, we can set database path to any location.

If you want to access database created by websql, then query path of database from Databases.db.

```
public String getWebViewDBPath() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 18) {
        return "app_webview/databases";
    } else {
        return "{any folder}";
    }
}

public String getDBFileName(ZoomRxApp ctx, String dbName) {
    String dbFilePath = getFilesDir().getParent() + "/" +  getWebViewDBPath() + "/Databases.db";
    SQLiteDatabase webSqlDb = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFilePath, null);
    Cursor result = null;
    String dbFileName = null;
    try {
        String query = "select * from Databases where name like '"+dbName+"'";
        result = webSqlDb.rawQuery(query, null);
        while (result != null && result.moveToNext()) {
            String origin = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("origin"));
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 18) {
                dbFileName = origin + "/" + result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("path"));
            } else {
                dbFileName = origin + "/" + result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("id"));
            }
            break;
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(result != null) {
            result.close();
        }
        if(webSqlDb != null) {
            webSqlDb.close();
        }
    }
}
```